# How do I write a comment which contains commands that contain the character ` (backtick)?

Tags: support, comments, markdown, code-formatting

I would like to use in a comment the following command:

[image]

How can I do that so that character " ` " before and after the word "Private" is visible?

Comment: @ Shadow Wizard: Thank you very much … I will delete my question in a few minutes

Comment: No need to delete. And adding a space after  the `@` cause it not to ping, I saw the comment by chance. :)